# Why does Python allow more recursion depth than the limit when running using IDLE's shell?

Tags: python, recursion

Python seems to allow more recursion depth than the actual limit defined (default 1000, here it is 20 to make it easier), when the script is run using IDLE shell 3.9.1 (coding the script in IDLE and then pressing F5), on Python 3.9.1 (tags/v3.9.1:1e5d33e, Dec  7 2020, 17:08:21) [MSC v.1927 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32 (Windows 10 1909, build 18363.1316).

With the code:

```py
import sys, inspect
sys.setrecursionlimit(20)
print("Recursion limit:", sys.getrecursionlimit()) #ouputs 20

recursionCounter = 0

def recursive():
    global recursionCounter
    recursionCounter += 1
    print("stack:", len(inspect.stack())) #starts at 5 (IDLE is adding some nested loops) but stops at 36, higher than the recursion limit 
    recursive()

          
try:
    recursive()
except RecursionError:
    print("RecursionError raised. recursionCounter value is:" , recursionCounter) #outputs 33
```

The full output is:

```
Recursion limit: 20
stack: 5
stack: 6
stack: 7
(...)
stack: 35
stack: 36
RecursionError raised. recursionCounter value is: 33
```

Same thing with a lowered or increased limit, whatever the recursion limit is set to, Python goes deeper than it, exceeding it by the same amount (13 here).

Is there something special with recursion limits or RecursionError that I missed and that can explain this effect?

Comment: You could put in a global counter to actually see how many times it's being called. It's always adding 22, but that might have to do with the printed output rather than the actual number of times the function was called.

Comment: Doing so shows that the number of times the function was actually called is exact to the number we can guess using the error message. I'm updating the post.

Comment: It's an interesting question, but to some extent, the exact depth shouldn't matter. If you are hitting the recursion limit, you are probably using recursion for something you shouldn't be.

Comment: Notice also that it's not strictly a *recursion* limit, but rather a limit on the size of the call stack.

Comment: I think there is some existing stack, on top of this the function call stack is getting built, that is why the size is different, I am guessing though

Comment: @chepner yes, I know that in practice it shouldn't matter but it's still strange.

Comment: Also, I can't replicate this using Python 3.8 or Python 3.9.

Comment: @JeanMichel what are you using to run the scripts? When I try just via `python script.py` it's not adding 22 to the number, it's working more as expected. Are you doing this through some notebook thing?

Comment: @RandomDavis I realised that this doesn't appear when running the script through a CLI. It's only occurs when creating the script with Python's default IDE and then running from here using IDLE's Shell (pressing F5). Edited my original post.

Comment: On my PC the the `actual limit = sys limit - 4`, I tried with some online compiler, the difference what it remains same for all given recursion limit like 1000 or 5 etc

Comment: @Epsi95 what's strange here it's that the actual limit is higher than the theoritical one. It has something to do with IDLE but I can't see what exactly.

Comment: I saw less, for example, if the limit 1000 then recursion can go upto 996. Something eating 4 :p

Comment: I am guessing there is already a stack on which all function in main.py is getting executedd

Comment: If there was a stack in which the functions in main were executed then it should have lowered the number of times the function got called, here it is increasing higher than the limit.

Comment: Yes, your case It seems increasing. But have you print `counter` ? `line repeated 1022` seems line repeating not the function

Comment: @JeanMichel seems that the limit simply takes your own code into account, but that the message indicates the total call depth. Also you never print `counter` so it's not clear how you're seeing its value when the recursion limit is hit.

Comment: @Epsi95 @RandomDavis, sorry again, updated the post, I can see the value of `counter` after the error was raised (using try except or IDLE's shell that goes into a REPL after the script crashed).

Comment: Strange, for me it is always lower than sys limit

Comment: great question, only Guido can answer :p (Y)

Comment: On python 3.7.4, Windows IDLE 32b, I have a consistent `raise_limit = sys_limit - 20`. This is an interesting question, can you specify what's your python version / environment?

Comment: Also, using the `inspect` module, `len(inspect.stack())` might help you by returning the current stack size

Comment: Seems like implementation-dependent trivia. What difference does it make--is there an actual use case/problem here? Most languages don't let you get or set the call stack size--it's dangerous to mess with and there's almost never any good use case for messing with it anyway.

Comment: Updated with the asked informations @LeMinaw.

Comment: @ggorlen There is no actual use case here, just strange behaviour to be explained.

Comment: With 3.10 in IDLE the actual limit seems to be 1024. That is of course a highly suggestive number but seems coincidental. With 3.11 I can get to 1027 before crashing.